# Time series sorting and insufficient part replace by NaN in python

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, datetime, time-series

I have a dataframe like this

```
index                 value
2014-05-21 09:00:00   0
2014-05-22 10:00:00   23.66
2014-05-22 11:00:00   7.54
2014-05-22 12:00:00   17.83
...
2017-07-10 23:00:00   9.43
```

the index is time (time step is 'hour') and first column is the value. And now
I would like to make a new dataframe which looks ike this

```
index          value
2014-05-21     [NaN, NaN, NaN ... 23.66, 7.54, 17.83, ...]
2014-05-22     [2.64, 7.43, 9.88, 0, 13.4, ...           ]
2014-05-23     [  ...                                    ] 
...
2017-07-10     [  ...                              , 9.43]
```

the index is  time (time step is 'day') and the value is a numpy arrange(or list ) that each one contain 24 values inside (24 hours data), and like the data in the first day, the missing data would automatically replace by "NaN"

Because in the end I would like to calculate the annual mean as below (ex. named df_average)

```
index value
1     [0.5, 5.67, 12.32, ... , 13.21]
2     [ 0, 13.65,  2.34, ... , 2.45 ]
3     [...                          ]
...
365   [...                          ]
```

which the column "value" could still show the average hourly value (24 values 
 inside) and the time series(index) are 365 or 365 (a year). and the "NaN" would be automatically skipped when calculating the average.

I tried some way but the missing value still confused me, and the code looks stupid and lengthy, do anyone have a better or smart way to solve it? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you do do something like this:

Where df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.arange(100,148),index=pd.date_range('2014-05-21 09:00:00',periods=48, freq='H'),columns=['value'])
```

Use `reindex` to add hours to the begin and end

```
df1 = df.reindex(pd.date_range(df.index.floor('D').min(), 
                 df.index.ceil('D').max(), freq='H'))[:-1]
```

Reshape dataframe using `unstack`:

```
df1 = df1.set_index([df1.index.floor('D'), df1.index.hour])['value']\
   .unstack().apply(lambda x : str(list(x)), axis=1)

print(df1)
```

Output:

```
2014-05-21                      [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 100.0, 101.0, 102.0, 103.0, 104.0, 105.0, 106.0, 107.0, 108.0, 109.0, 110.0, 111.0, 112.0, 113.0, 114.0]
2014-05-22    [115.0, 116.0, 117.0, 118.0, 119.0, 120.0, 121.0, 122.0, 123.0, 124.0, 125.0, 126.0, 127.0, 128.0, 129.0, 130.0, 131.0, 132.0, 133.0, 134.0, 135.0, 136.0, 137.0, 138.0]
2014-05-23                                  [139.0, 140.0, 141.0, 142.0, 143.0, 144.0, 145.0, 146.0, 147.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]
dtype: object
```

#### Edit to add annual by hour row

```
df2 = df.groupby([df.index.year,df.index.hour]).mean().unstack().apply(lambda x : str(list(x)), axis=1)

df_out = pd.concat([df1,df2])
```

Output:

```
2014-05-21 00:00:00                      [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 100.0, 101.0, 102.0, 103.0, 104.0, 105.0, 106.0, 107.0, 108.0, 109.0, 110.0, 111.0, 112.0, 113.0, 114.0]
2014-05-22 00:00:00    [115.0, 116.0, 117.0, 118.0, 119.0, 120.0, 121.0, 122.0, 123.0, 124.0, 125.0, 126.0, 127.0, 128.0, 129.0, 130.0, 131.0, 132.0, 133.0, 134.0, 135.0, 136.0, 137.0, 138.0]
2014-05-23 00:00:00                                  [139.0, 140.0, 141.0, 142.0, 143.0, 144.0, 145.0, 146.0, 147.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]
2014                                                                   [127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126]
dtype: object
```

Comment: This is awesome and the code is concise !! 

Btw how can I calculate the annual mean as mentioned in the last ? 

I tried to use "groupby" before but in this case the values in the column seems non-computable ?

Comment: `df.groupby(df.index.year)['value'].mean()`

Comment: Oh... an annual per hour in the same format as the data?

Comment: @Chi See updated to solution.  I think that is what you want.

Comment: I tried but the answer seems not correct. in the last I need the average hourly data and the time step is a year (like mentined in the last, named "df_average")

Comment: I tried to modify a litte and it successed, thanks a lot!